# Synaptics Touchpad hangs when system disk activity is high

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 3543 laptop, with Windows 10 and newest drivers from Dell website. When system disk activity is around 100%, then the touchpad stops responding (i.e. the cursor does not move when i move my finger on the touchpad). The problem can be resolved by killing SynTPEnh.exe, but then I lose multitouch/gestures. Does anybody know a fix for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the priority of `SynTPEnh.exe`? You can use TaskManager to do this, but the priority will revert at the next boot. If you are happy that this is a solution there are programs to make the change automatically on boot-up.

Comment: It's "Above normal" by default, changed to "High", we'll see if it helps.

Comment: Well, it appears that setting the priority to "High" helped, but I still would like to know the reason why this program even needs to access the disk constantly.

Comment: I don't think it does: I think it is being swapped out and in repeatedly.

Comment: Why would it be? I rarely have less than 2GB of free RAM.

Comment: If that's true even when you have 100% disc activity, then I have no explanation. Though I have seen threads complaining that Windows can swap to disc even when there is free memory available. I certainly agree with you that the application itself should have no reason to access the disc.

Comment: Solved the problem, by switching to Gentoo, I guess it's okay